# UIScrollView with scrolling buttons issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to create `UIScrollView` with scrolling buttons.So when user press left arrow button, scroll must scroll properly.

The issue is: when I click button 3 times quickly scroll can't scroll properly (because of many calls of `scrollRectToVisible`). May be I can stop current animation before next animation?

P.S. If I set `[self scrollScrollViewToIndex:index animated:NO]` everything works properly, but I need animation

**Here is my code:**

```
- (void)scrollScrollViewToIndex:(int)index animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"scrolled to index: %d", index);
    CGFloat offsetX = CGRectGetWidth(_scrollMain.frame) * index;
    CGRect scrollRect = CGRectMake(offsetX, 0, CGRectGetWidth(_scrollMain.frame), CGRectGetHeight(_scrollMain.frame));    
    [_scrollMain scrollRectToVisible:scrollRect animated:animated];
//    [self.scrollMain setContentOffset:CGPointMake(offsetX, 0) animated:animated];
}

- (IBAction)leftArrowPressed:(id)sender
{
    int indexOfVoucher = [_arrayVouchers indexOfObject:_voucher];
    indexOfVoucher--;
    self.voucher = [_arrayVouchers objectAtIndex:indexOfVoucher];
    [self updateViewWithVoucherWithScrolling:YES];
}

- (IBAction)rightArrowPressed:(id)sender
{
    int indexOfVoucher = [_arrayVouchers indexOfObject:_voucher];
    indexOfVoucher++;
    self.voucher = [_arrayVouchers objectAtIndex:indexOfVoucher];
    [self updateViewWithVoucherWithScrolling:YES];
}

- (void)updateViewWithVoucherWithScrolling:(BOOL)withScrolling
{
    int indexOfVoucher = [_arrayVouchers indexOfObject:_voucher];
    _leftArrowButton.hidden = _rightArrowButton.hidden = NO;
    if (indexOfVoucher == 0)
    {
        _leftArrowButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (indexOfVoucher == [_arrayVouchers count] - 1)
    {
        self.rightArrowButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (withScrolling)
    {
       [self scrollScrollViewToIndex:indexOfVoucher animated:YES]; 
    }
}
```

**update:**
working code according to Mar0ux's advice

```
- (void)scrollScrollViewToIndex:(int)index animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"scrolled to index: %d", index);
    CGFloat offsetX = CGRectGetWidth(_scrollMain.frame) * index;

    if (animated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState //Multiple options
                         animations:^ {
                             //                         [self.scrollMain setContentOffset:CGPointMake(offsetX, 0) animated:NO];
                             CGRect scrollRect = CGRectMake(offsetX, 0, CGRectGetWidth(_scrollMain.frame), CGRectGetHeight(_scrollMain.frame));
                             [_scrollMain scrollRectToVisible:scrollRect animated:NO];
                         }
                         completion:^ (BOOL finished) {

                         }];
    }
    else
    {
        CGRect scrollRect = CGRectMake(offsetX, 0, CGRectGetWidth(_scrollMain.frame), CGRectGetHeight(_scrollMain.frame));
        [_scrollMain scrollRectToVisible:scrollRect animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try using `setContentOffset:animated:YES` method.

Comment: I've tried (you can see it in commented code), but it works even worse

Comment: You can always animate the `contentOffset` property yourself and use `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option.

Comment: --->>>>The issue is: when I click button 3 times quickly scroll can't scroll properly (because of many calls of scrollRectToVisible)       ------->>> Ans ---- So just disable the button after giving first time action.

Comment: Mar0ux advice helped, please, write your answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: I don't think you entered @Mar0ux correctly in your comment so I just did :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always animate the `contentOffset` property yourself and use `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option. As soon as the second animation begins, the first will end, and by using current state option, the second animation will start from where the first left off.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1) do you really want the user hammering on the button while its scrolling? If so then I suggest that your UI design may need redesign.

2) when you perturb the UI in an action method, its best to post other UI actions by dispatching a block with the code to the main queue - the button hiliting will look better.

3) in your specific case, you could in the action method disable the button, then re-enable it when the scrolling has stopped.